# How can I restore the original text after it has been translated with micorosoft translator api

Tags: javascript, html, microsoft-translator

I have been able to translate a paragraph from English to Spanish using the Microsoft translator API with an AJAX call when a user clicks a button on my webpage. I would like to give them the ability to toggle back to the original text without having to translate the Spanish text back to English. When I view the page source I can see the original text, but I am not sure how to display that back to the user.

```js
function Translate()
{
  var from = "en", to = "es", text = $('.Translate').text();
  
  var s = document.createElement("script");
  s.src = "http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Ajax.svc/Translate" +
      "?appId=Bearer " + encodeURIComponent(window.accessToken) +
      "&from=" + encodeURIComponent(from) +
      "&to=" + encodeURIComponent(to) +
      "&text=" + encodeURIComponent(text) +
      "&oncomplete=MyCallback";
  document.body.appendChild(s);
}

function MyCallback(response)
{
  $('.Translate').text(response);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnTranslate" onclick="Translate()" class="etsButton">Translate</button>
<button id="btnRestore" onclick="Restore()" class="etsButton">Restore</button>

<div style="padding:10px;" class="Translate">
To be, or not to be: that is the question:
Whether 'tis nobler in the mind to suffer
The slings and arrows of outrageous fortune,
Or to take arms against a sea of troubles,
And by opposing end them? 
</div>
```

Comment: Can you translate in other direction?

Comment: Yes, but I believe that would count toward my monthly limit of characters I can translate, and was hoping there was a better way. Also, the re-translated text is not quite the same as the original.

Comment: I did not know about that limitation. David's solution seems to be more flexible as you can append more then one language translation. Ultimately you can keep translated messages in a separate files (one per language) and just query those files for a message with given key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Viewing the page source does not show you the current HTML for the page.  The problem is that your line `$('.Translate').text(response);` destroys the original text that was on your page.

If you want to be able to switch back, then you need to put the translated text into a new div.  Then you can just show and hide the divs to toggle between the displayed version.

Answer (score 1):

You can remember original text before translating it by storing it in a variable, and then in `restore()` function you can replace `text` with the content of this variable. But because this temporary variable should set and get it`s value in different functions, it should be in a higher scope. In your case it would be global one, but keep in mind that is not recommended.

```
var originalText; 

function Translate()
{
  var from = "en", to = "es", text = $('.Translate').text();

  originalText = text;

  var s = document.createElement("script");
  s.src = "http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Ajax.svc/Translate" +
      "?appId=Bearer " + encodeURIComponent(window.accessToken) +
      "&from=" + encodeURIComponent(from) +
      "&to=" + encodeURIComponent(to) +
      "&text=" + encodeURIComponent(text) +
      "&oncomplete=MyCallback";
  document.body.appendChild(s);
}

function restore(){
   $('.Translate').text(originalText);
}
```